# How do I get my sideloaded books to appear in the Books section?

Tags: kindle-fire, sideloading

I have some DRM-free books that I purchased before acquiring my Kindle Fire.  When I sideload them on to the device, they end up under the Documents menu instead of in with the other books.

How can I get them to go in the right spot in the device's UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) program, you can clear the `[pdoc]` tag from the mobi file.

[image]

Remove the tag from this textbox, and convert (back) to .mobi.

[image]

Finish by sideloading the converted files via USB or Dropbox.